# Adobe Acrobat 9.0 professional crashes without error on Windows Server 2008 RS under terminal services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, adobe-acrobat

When I start Adobe Acrobat 9.0 professional on Windows Server 2008 R2 it works for a few seconds and then either freezes (goes translucent white) or simple disappears altogether instantly.

Troubleshooting:

- Tried compatibility mode for WXPsp2, Windows Server 2008
- Tried submitting failure to Microsoft for solutions; none
- Tried using Windows' recommended compatibility settings; didn't work
- Looked for any log messages in Windows System and Windows Application log; there are no messages
- Did a repair of the software
- Did a uninstall-reboot-install

I am stumped. Any suggestions I could try to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you applied the latest 9.3.3 update? The last few minor updates have addressed stability issues.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I had to install 9.3.1, 9.3.2 and 9.3.3 and it now works.